# Salesforce Case Management Integration (Bi-directional) with Another Ticketing Platform Using MS Graph

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, salesforce, integration, ticket-system

I was looking for a suitable solution to integrate the Salesforce case management with another ticketing platform using Microsoft Graph. The connection should be bi-directional and both platforms will frequently exchange information with the required field mapped. Can anyone suggest to me the best way to accomplish these tasks?

Answer (score 0):

- *The best way would be using **Salesforce Microsoft Graph Connector** for integrating **Salesforce case management**.*
- *You need to add the connector to **Microsoft 365 admin center** and then configure the **connection settings**.*

[image]

- *For complete information go through Graph API [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/salesforce-connector).*